# C programme pointer point to multiple-dimension table

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

The following code print "1" on the screen. and my question is about the comment line. I thought ptr is the address of the first element a[0][0], so *p is already the value of 1, 
where am I wrong? for the address of multiple-dimension table, could anyone suggest some tutorial? I'm always confused. thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void fun(int **p);

int main()
{
    int a[3][4] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 8, 7, 8, 9, 0};
    int *ptr;
    ptr = &a[0][0]; // *ptr = *&a[0][0]=a[0][0]
    fun(&ptr);
    return 0;
}
void fun(int **p)
{
    printf("%d\n", **p);
}
```

Comment: seems like few people use/understand *base pointers* anymore, that is, just "a" after declaring int a[3][4]...

Comment: You are not wrong. Output is 1, that is what you expected. You are sending address of pointer `ptr` to function `fun()`, so to get value you have to dereference it twice, that is what you did. Where do you think you are wrong?

`p` is double pointer. `*p` = `ptr` = `&a[0][0]`, and `**p` = `*ptr` = `*&a[0][0]` = `a[0][0]` = `1`

Comment: @Vinay I see where I am wrong. Like you said, I send the address of ptr, which had been omitted by me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Pointer is a variable which holds the memory location of another variable
So ptr is a pointer which points to the address of variable a[0][0] which is 1
because  a[3][4] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 8, 7, 8, 9, 0};

```
 ptr = &a[0][0];
```

Which is the first element of the first row (since a[ ] [ ] is a two dimensional array)

```
fun(&ptr);
```

function *fun* passes the address of the pointer **ptr**

In the function

```
void fun(int **p)
```

it takes address as argument and a pointer **p** takes that address as argument,ie; pointer to a pointer

p points to the address of ptr , where ptr points to the adress a[0][0]. So the expected output should be 1

For further information on pointers and arrays refer to this link : 
http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm